# apple distribution certificate causes 14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification

I have created an iPhone app that support notifications, by following this tutorial by [Ali Hafizji](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

when running in production I get the following error:
14094410:SSL routines:

```
SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

itunes shows the distribution provisioning :

```
Enabled Services: Game Center, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications
Expires:Sep 15, 2015
Status:Active
```

I've loaded the pem file to the server and call it like so:

```
    theCertfile ='./CK_production.pem'
    theHost = ( 'gateway.push.apple.com', 2195 )
    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket( socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ), certfile = theCertfile )
    ssl_sock.connect( theHost )
    ssl_sock.write( theNotification )
    ssl_sock.close()
```

I understand Apple stopped using SSL 3.0 to send push notifications, and we need to use TSL instead the apple documentation doesn't have an example, can anyone point me to a tutorial, for Python/Django? (just to be clear I did google for a tutorial but didn't find one)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Apple stopped using SSL 3.0 to send push notifications.

Why? A news published in late September 2014 said it was not secure anymore. [Read Apple note](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a)

You can google "BEAST attack" for more information.

Now?
Your service needs to use TLS.
Here is [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

Comment: do you have a link for tutorial on how to set TLS notifications??

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, turned out that I was running the script with PHP command on my Mac terminal. Copied the files to my server and it is working now.